# How can i see profile details according to id?

Tags: php, codeigniter, profile, detailsview

I am trying to see profile details but there is a problem about getting 'id'. But I have some errors: Severity: Warning

Message: Missing argument 1 for customers::details()
Filename: controllers/customers.php
 And,

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: id

Filename: controllers/customers.php

Here is my model:

```
function selectCustomer(){

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('customers');

    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result();
}
 function detailsCustomer($id){
    //$id= $_GET['ID'];
    //$this->db->select('*');
    //$this->db->from('customers');
    $this->db->where('ID', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get('customers');

}
```

Here is my controller:

```
    publicfunction viewCustomers(){
     $this->load->model('CustomerModel');
     $result = $this->CustomerModel->selectCustomer();
     return $result;}

     public function details($id){

     $this->load->model('CustomerModel');

     $data["result"] = $this->CustomerModel->detailsCustomer($id);

        if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')){
         error_reporting(0);
         $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
         $data1['email'] = $session_data['email'];
         $this->load->view('navbarview', $data1);
         $this->load->view('Detailsview',$data);
     }else{
         redirect('home', 'refresh');
     }
 }
```

Here is my view page:

```
...
    <table class="table table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Surname</th>
          <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
                  <?php  foreach ($user_data as $row) {
                echo "    
        <table class='table table-hover'>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>".$row->name."</td>
          <td>".$row->surname."</td>
          <td>".$row->email."</td>";?>


          <td><a href='http://localhost/CRM/customers/details/<?php echo $id;?>' type='button' class='btn btn-info'>Details</a></td>
      <td><a href='Editview.php' data-toggle='modal' class='btn btn-success'>Edit</a></td> 
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table> <?}?>  

    ...
```

Comment: You have a   public function details($id){
Where is this called?

Comment: Basically you are not passing a ID into the details method. Try to var_dump the $id just before the details method is called and see if it is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
function detailsCustomer($id){
   $this->db->where('ID', $id);
   $query = $this->db->get('customers');
   return $query->result();
}
```

you misdeed to add return $query->result();

also in view

change

```
        <td><a href='http://localhost/CRM/customers/details/<?php echo $id;?>' type='button' class='btn btn-info'>Details</a></td>
```

into

```
       <td><a href='http://localhost/CRM/customers/details/<?php echo $row->id;?>' type='button' class='btn btn-info'>Details</a></td>
```